# Why ubuntu doesn't start getting ae_not_found error?

Tags: 20.04

I have an old computer with Ubuntu 20 that stops working suddenly. The computer doesn't open the ubuntu, I got this error:

```
    ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND. While resolving a named reference package element - SATA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
fsck.ext4: Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying to open /dev/sdb5
/dev/sdb5:
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

fsck exited with status code 8
```

I tried to add acpi=off on the Linux line on the boot file configuration but doesn't work. I also tried to reinstall the ubuntu but I got the same error  ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND. While resolving a named reference package element - SATA (20190816/dspkginit-438)

If I try to run: e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdb I got this error:
Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and in `terminal`, try `sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb5`. Report back.

Comment: Your comment works!!! Thank you so much @heynnema, you saved my life!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and in `terminal`, try `sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb5`.

It's all working now.

Comment: This solution works for me!

Answer (score -1):

The <device> it's referring to is the device containing the filesystem.  The error message you related indicates the device is /dev/sdb5 , not /dev/sdb.  That's why it tells you that it's a partition table.  Your cmd line should be more like "e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdb5".  The problem doing that might be that this filesystem might be in use when you have booted into Ubuntu.  You may have to boot with a live CD or live USB in order to try and repair your filesystem.  But beware, in that case your filesystem may not be on sdb5, it might be on some other disk name.  You can use the blkid command to tell you what is on a disk or disk partition.  For example, you could run blkid /dev/sdb5 (or sudo blkid /dev/sda5) and it would tell you if there is a filesystem, what its UUID is, and any filesystem label it might have.  If it DOES have a label, you can try e2fsck LABEL=yourFilesystemLabelHere (or even with its UUID, but those are long and complicated).  If nothing else, you can use sudo blkid /dev/sd(something) (e.g. sda1, sda2, ..., sdb1, sdb2, sdb3,... sdc1, sdc2, etc.) until you find your filesystem that's now on sdb5.

Tough to diagnose remotely, but you're right, you may have an issue deeper than just a corrupted filesystem.  Not sure what to suggest for that, but at least maybe I have helped with how to use some more tools.

As "It's me" suggests, you may want to add "acpi=off" along with "nomodeset" in /etc/default/grub , then run sudo update-grub, and perhaps reboot.  That way your system will always boot with acpi=off.  Something to try anyway.

Comment: You've basically copied my earlier comment. `acpi=off` and `nomodeset` are not applicable to disk related problems.