# ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while resolving a named reference package element - sata

Tags: acpi

I have a 10 year old laptop (Quanta TW9) that gives me the following error:

0.333551 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while resolving a named reference package element - sata (20190816/dspkginit-438)

The error stays on the screen for about 30 seconds and then it goes away. Then I can use my laptop. Sometimes it freezes that causes me to turn it off by hand but I don't think this is the cause.

The error does not go away upon reinstall. Since I don't have dual OS I cannot say whether I would face the same error if I tried to boot windows.

I reely want to get rid of this error since it irritates me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: Sometimes it helps using your hard disk in ide mode. you can change that in your bios

Comment: Yes, that message is actually a warning that bugs us, but it can be ignored. But also see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245813/why-ubuntu-doesnt-start-getting-ae-not-found-error)